# AMD graphic card with AMD processor or NVidia card with AMD processor

Tags: graphics-cards, processor

Planning to buy a graphic card looking at 6950 XT or Nvidia 3090 Ti.
I have AMD Process "AMD Ryzen 7 2700X Eight-Core Processor, 4150 Mhz, 8 Core(s), 16 Logical Processor(s)" someone told me that AMD graphic card work better with AMD processor should i get 6950XT anyone now is that a case ?

Comment: Over the years there have been moments where a new tech comes out on one CPU/GPU or another and it is only supported by a certain GPU/CPU too. Then a couple years later both brands support the new tech and the advantage is gone. You should always drill in to *why* somebody says using AMD CPU with AMD GPU might be faster. A recent relevant example of this would be resizable BAR support.

Answer (score 1):

What handles the GPU's task is the OS using drivers and abstraction model.
There some times synergy between certain GPU's and CPU's (Mainly related to the PCI-E lanes).

Also you can find combinations which work better, but it usually has nothing to do with the fast the GPU and CPU are made by the same company.

Personally, unless you have something with CUDA, I'd go with AMD.